# Can 章 be used to mean "story arc"'?

Tags: meaning

I was reading an interview with a author about her serialized story

『やが』も佳境といいますか、最終章と呼んでいいところまで到達しました。最後まで見届けていただけると……って、こんな「もうすぐ終わり」みたいな雰囲気を出してしまっていいのかな？（笑）。

So, in my opinion, I think it makes more sense if 章 refers to a story arc in this comment (the last one) rather than chapter, but when looking in the dictionary, the only meaning for 章 is "chapter" or "section". Does it really mean chapter in this context or can this word also be used to say "arc"?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing why "final chapter" doesn't work well as a translation in this extract. Is there more context? I think the word used for "story arc" is ストーリー性, which, as in English, can refer to the entire plot or just part of it.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but I think there's a part that says "I have reached a place that I can all final chapter". And since the last chapter is yet to come and the verb is in past, it made me wonder if it could mean arc or if it always means chapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When technical correctness matters, 章 normally means "chapter", something smaller than 部 ("part") and bigger than 節 ("section"). But 最終章 in this context just vaguely refers to "the final part" or "climax" of the entire series, and you should not try to analyze it too strictly. Perhaps even the author does not know exactly when the 最終章 started. 最終章 can be used more or less idiomatically (e.g. 人生の最終章). It could have been 最終節 or 最終盤.